# A die is rolled 24 independent times. Let Y be the sum of the 24 resulting values. What is the variance of Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A die is rolled 24 independent times. Let Y be the sum of the 24 resulting values. What is the variance of Y?

I know how to find the mean of Y, but I'm having some trouble finding the variance of X in order to find the variance of Y. I know Var(y)=24(Var(x)).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually the value of E(Y) is irrelevant. What do you know about the variance of a sum of random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance is
$$\sum_x\left(x-\mu\right)^2P(x)$$
For a six-sided die, $P(x)$ is always $1/6$, and $\mu=7/2$.

That should get you there.